# Scala-maven-plugin failed to execute

Tags: java, scala, maven, scala-maven-plugin

I am trying to use the scala-maven-plugin for one of my project. I get the following error when I run `mvn package`:

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin:2.15.0:compile (default) on project
>   test_pro: wrap: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process
>   exited with an error: 1

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
....

<build>
<sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
<testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
<plugins>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.15.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
        <goal>testCompile</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <args>
          <arg>-make:transitive</arg>
          <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
          <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
        </args>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
....
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

I am a Mac user (using Terminal) and have Java and Maven installed.

Comment: In case you didn't notice, I updated my answer. The `-make:transitive` option is no longer accepted by the _Scala_ compiler and so that line should be removed from your configuration. Let me know if my answer worked for you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a *very* old version of the plugin (dating to around 2010), and may not be compatible with recent *Java* & *Scala* releases. Incidentally, it has been renamed to the [`scala-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/davidB/scala-maven-plugin) and the latest release is 3.3.2:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.2</version>
  <!-- etc. -->
</plugin>
```

Give that a try...

Also, I strongly recommend using [*SBT*](https://www.scala-sbt.org/) over *Maven* if you're primarily working with *Scala* (*SBT* handles combined *Java* and *Scala* builds too). It has a steeper learning curve than *Maven*, but is well worth the effort...

**UPDATE**

BTW, I should mention that `-make:transitive` is no longer accepted by the *Scala* compiler, so you should remove that line.

Comment: Thanks very much, @MikeAllen. Actually, your response could solve a part of the problem. I have another error that I think is not related to this topic.